# List numbering issue in latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, theorems, enumitem, etoolbox

Suppose that I have this simple code

```
\begin{theorem}
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
 \item[(1)] This is the first item 
 \item[(2)] This is the second item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

My question is: How to make the labels of the items of the list ((i), (ii), and (iii)) at the very beginning of the line, precisely under the **Theorem** word.

**Note:** I use

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*,font=\upshape}}
```

at the preamble of the code.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make the labels of the items of the list ((i), (ii), and (iii)) at the very beginning of the line, precisely under the "Theorem" word?

Here's a solution that employs the machinery of the `amsthm`, `enumitem`, and `etoolbox` packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{amsthm} % for \newtheoremstyle, \theoremstyle, and \newtheorem macros
\newtheoremstyle{break}% % See p. 9 of user guide of amsthm package
   {}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{brktheorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{enumitem} % for \setlist macro
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \AtBeginEnvironment macro
\AtBeginEnvironment{brktheorem}{\setlist[enumerate,1]{%
   nolistsep, left=0pt, align=left, label=\upshape(\roman*),
   % See p. 10 of user guide of amsthm package:
   before=\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}
   }} 

\begin{document}

\begin{brktheorem} 
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This is the first item.
  \item This is the second item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{brktheorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to define a special enumeration environment, which I name `roster` (it was so called in AMS-TeX).

For the occasional theorem that starts with `roster`, just add `\mbox{}` (after the `\label`, if you need one), but avoid theorems with just enumerations: introducing them with a few words is usually better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{roster}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[roster]{
  nolistsep,
  label=(\roman*),
  font=\upshape,
  left=0pt,
  align=left,
  widest=(iii),
  labelsep=0pt,
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\mbox{}
\begin{roster}
\item This is the first item 
\item This is the second item 
\end{roster}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]